# How can we interpret the components of a polarization four-vector?

Tags: quantum-spin, polarization, dirac-equation, spinors, chirality

The four components of a Dirac spinor [can be interpreted](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/147386/) in terms of left-chiral and right-chiral spin up and spin down states.

**How can we interpret the four components of a polarization four vector $\epsilon_\mu$?** In particular, the [spin operators for the spin-1 representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_(physics)#Higher_spins) are $3\times 3$ matrices and therefore, the corresponding spinors that can be interpreted directly are 3-component vectors.

Comment: my answer to this question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/273621/what-are-the-actual-transformation-properties-of-dirac-spinors-u-sigmap/289046#289046 explains in detail the polarizations for any spin, including thus case of a spin-1 in a 4-vector rep.